# char * ptr = "String"; What encoding is used by default?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ascii

What is the encoding that is used here.

If I go peak at `ptr[0]` - will `'S'` be encoded in `ASCII/utf-8`.

How do I know what is the encoding that is used ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

For the letter `S`, UTF-8 *is* ASCII. For the more general case, the ISO C standard (assuming you're talking C) does not mandate the encoding.

It merely states that a certain minimum number of source characters have to be made available, for both the source and execution environments (the first is where you *develop* your code, the second where you *run* it - they may be vastly different beasts).

That's all covered in, for C11, `5.2.1 Character sets`, which specifies source and execution character sets. Later sections of `5.2` cover trigraphs, multibyte characters and so on.